# What are the steps to use Python or Polygon SDK to create a Polygon blockchain account without using any wallet?

Tags: python-3.x, ethereum, blockchain, polygon, web3py

Can you provide a detailed guide on how to use Python to create a user account on the Polygon Proof-of-Stake (PoS) blockchain, including all necessary steps and explanations?

Can you provide a step-by-step guide on how to create a user account on the Polygon Proof-of-Stake (PoS) blockchain using Python, without the need for a wallet, as current resources and documentation only show how to create an account with a wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Polygon account, like any other [EVM-compatible](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/evm-compatible) blockchain account, is just a 256-bit random number as a private key. A [wallet](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/wallet) is then a collection of these private keys.

- Any cryptographically safe random number generator can generate you a number needed for the private key
- Then you can import this number to Web3.py, Web3.js or similar library you interact with your blockchain JSON-RPC node
- [Here are instructions to generate a private key on a command line](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/82926/620) - you can use `python` command with web3.py library
- [Here are instructions to import a private key to web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#reading-a-private-key-from-an-environment-variable)

No Polygon SDK or other SDK needed.